# How to increase heap size for ws_ant.sh when deploying on WebSphere 8.5 (64-bit Linux)

Tags: java, automation, jenkins, websphere, ant

**TL;DR -- How do I give `ws_ant.sh` and/or the `<wsInstallApp>` task more heap at runtime?**

I am attempting to deploy a relatively large (~160-MB) EAR file to WebSphere 8.5 running on a 64-bit Linux platform.

Here is the task I have in my `build.xml`:

```
<wsInstallApp
    ear="/my/ear/file/location/New.EAR"
    properties="jvm.properties"
    options="-appname myNewEarApp -update -deployws"
    host="localhost"
    conntype="SOAP"
    user="the_username"
    password="not_telling_you"
    failonerror="true" />
```

Executing it with the `ws_ant.sh` packaged with WAS results in an `OutOfMemoryError` and heap dumps.

So, I need to increase the heap available to the task (or ws_ant itself?) at runtime, but I cannot figure out the proper place to do so.  I tried [modifying wsadmin.sh](http://www.websphereapplicationserver.com/), and while that has an effect if I run my deployment as a Jython script with `wsadmin.sh` directly, it does not seem to have any impact whatsoever on the execution of `<wsInstallApp>` from within the Ant script.

According to [the IBM documentation of wsInstallApp](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/ant/tasks/InstallApplication.html?lang=en):

> The **properties** attribute is optional and it contains a java properties file containing attributes to set in the JVM System properties

In my `jvm.properties` file, I tried:

```
[user@localhost]$ cat jvm.properties
-Xms4096m
-Xmx4096m
```

That had no effect.  Executing `ws_ant.sh` with the `-v` verbose flag showed that, somewhere, the -Xmx value is set as `-Xmx256m`.  I tried several other hair-brained combinations and formats, but nothing seems to work.

I also tried adding arguments onto the `ws_ant.sh` call:

```
[user@localhost]$ ws_ant.sh -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -v -f build.xml was.deploy
```

... but that also seems to do nothing.

**What am I doing wrong?**  I concede that, if pressed, I could probably meet my requirements by re-writing the deployment using `wsadmin.sh` and a Jython script, but I'm trying to leverage some extensive Ant scripting from a different EAR application.

**Alternatives?** I also recognize that I *could* use the `<wsadmin>` Ant task to call some Jython scripts from within Ant-- I have not yet tried this-- but again, we already have some extensive scripting otherwise.  **What are the relative advantages and disadvantages of one way versus the other?** (i.e., executing `wsadmin.sh`/Jython script via `<[ssh]exec>` or `<wsadmin>` versus `<wsInstallApp>` [and its "ws_____" siblings]).

Comment: I had the same problem and found no other solution except directly modifying ws_ant.sh. I believe you can get comment on this from WAS developers at https://developer.ibm.com/answers/

Answer (score 0):

Try attribute jvmMaxMemory

```
<wsInstallApp
    ear="/my/ear/file/location/New.EAR"
    jvmMaxMemory="1024M"
    options="-appname myNewEarApp -update -deployws"
    host="localhost"
    conntype="SOAP"
    user="the_username"
    password="not_telling_you"
    failonerror="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For ws_ant.sh you have to use the **JVM_EXTRA_CMD_ARGS** env variable.

```
export JVM_EXTRA_CMD_ARGS="-Xms1G -Xmx2G"
sh $WEBSPHERE_HOME/bin/ws_ant.sh -f was-build.xml
```

To prove the point, swap the min and max sizes "-Xms2G -Xmx1G", and you will get the error:

```
VMJ9GC019E -Xms too large for -Xmx
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9gc26(2): Failed to initialize
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using Maven for deployment and I can confirm, adding jvmMaxMemory to the wsInstallApp helped. I had to fork the original plugin and add the support for it.